# Macro variable from other macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Let say I want to create a macro variable like:

```
%let year=2019;

%let ye = SUBSTR(%year,3,2) (I want to extract 19 from 2019).
```

But it does not work. Do we have any of creating such a macro variable like this?

Update: My code in fact is like

```
%let yearend = 2019
% let monthend = 04
```

And now I want to create a macro variable like "data1904" in order to use the dataset named "data1904" in my library. So what I want to create is something like

```
%let dataname= CAT(SUBSTR(%yearend,3,2),%monthend)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't use the answers provided. Did you read the linked page in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use & to reference a macro variable, not %. 
When you use a function in macro code you need to wrap it in `%SYSFUNC()` so the compiler can [differentiate between text and code](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p1o13d7wb2zfcnn19s5ssl2zdxvi.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

```
%let ye = %sysfunc(substr(&year, 3, 2));
```

Or alternatively there is the `%SUBSTR()` macro [function](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n0nq1hkovbu54en1h78i6ci7gz51.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) which allows you to skip the %SYSFUNC().

```
%let ye = %substr(&year, 3, 2);
```

Comment: And now, I want to create another macro variable that depends on %ye. I tried: %let base = abc&ye (to get abc20) but it does work. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @tmtran99 show the problem code and SAS log in a new question.

Comment: Your example should work so you're likely doing something else wrong. As @Richard indicated, please show your code.

Comment: I updated the code in my question, please take a look at it . Thanks